# House Lizard's SFX

Tags: sfx

okay..may b this is not the right place to put this question since this a discussion forum.. but i am in need of a small help . i need a house lizard's sound asap ..can anyone help me out in this matter please?  i have tried searching free sfx sites but couldnt get it..

Answer (score 2):

What type of sound?

Vocalizations? Footsteps? Tongue lick?

If I were you, I would just make the vocalization myself and do some leaf-finger-footsteps, and get a wet rubber band for some tongue-swinging action.

Comment: @Utopia : i am looking for vocalizations.. particularly the 'tick tick' sound that it makes! 